# PHP . How to insert an array at a given index

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I want to insert an array at a given index in PHP.

For Example.

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [music_id] => 2
            [m_title] => Rolling In The Deep
            [m_cover_image] => 
            [m_file_path] => Rolling_In_The_Deep_Music_File_-1523020121.mp3
            [m_description] => 
            [m_artist_id] => Adele
            [m_genre_id] => 
            [m_post_date] => 2018-04-06 18:08:41
            [m_is_deleted] => NO
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [music_id] => 1
            [m_title] => Hello
            [m_cover_image] => 
            [m_file_path] => Hello_Music_File_-1523020071.mp3
            [m_description] => 
            [m_artist_id] => Adele
            [m_genre_id] => 
            [m_post_date] => 2018-04-06 18:07:51
            [m_is_deleted] => NO
        )
)
```

**Array 2**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [m_title] => Sponser 1
            [m_file_path] => Sponser_1_Music_File_-1523020307.mp3
            [m_is_deleted] => NO
        )

)
```

I want to select an index to insert my array 2 .The array 1 should make room for the array 2 at the specified index .The content in array 1 after the specified index should move down to make room.

I have searched related function such as **array_slice()**  and **array_splice()** but i am unable to make the results according to my requirements.

Looking forward to your answers .Thanks

Comment: Look at `array_splice()` with length set to zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = array(array('pos1', 1),array('pos2', 2), array('pos3', 3));
$array2 = array(2=>array('newpos3', 3));
$pos=0;
foreach($array2 as $k=>$v) {
  foreach($array1 as $kA=>$vA) {
    if ($k==$kA) {
        $pos = $k;
    }
  }
  array_splice($array1, $pos, 0, array($v));
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array1);
echo '</pre>';
```

Something like this. Goes through both arrays and checks for the right position. Then inserts it with array_splice();